# Choosing a function whose Fourier coefficients are the given sequence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, weak-convergence

$\{c_n\}_{n\in Z}$ is a complex sequence, $S_n(x)$ and $K_m(x)$ are defined as follows
$$S_n(x)=\sum_{k=-n}^{n}c_ke^{ikx}$$
$$K_m(x)=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}S_n(x).
$$
$\{K_n\}$ is bounded in $L^p((-π,π))$,$1＜p≤+∞$. Show that there exists $f\in L^p((-π,π))$ s.t.$$ c_n=\frac{1}{2π}\int_{-π}^{π}fe^{-inx}dx,
$$ for all $n\in Z$.

> I already konw there exist a subsequence of ${K_{n_{l}}}$ weakly converge to some point in  $L^p((-π,π))$.But what can I do next? Could someone give me some details? Thank you!

Comment: If you know that $K_{n}$ (or its subsequent) converges weakly to , say g then what are Fourier coefficients of g? For each $k$ they should be the same as the limit of k-th Fourier coefficient of $K_{n}$. But this is just $c_{k}$.

Comment: Thank you! I work it out!